# Show/Hide Buttons inside a PictureBox

Tags: c#, show-hide, picturebox, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have a problem when I show/hide some buttons inside a PictureBox , they show/hide but I can't click them, if I disable the hide part in MouseLeave event it works but when I make it hide, not working for some reason that I can't understand.

Here is the code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox picB = new PictureBox();
        Button btn1 = new Button();
        Button btn2 = new Button();
        picB.Size = new Size(130, 70);
        btn1.Text = "btn1";
        btn2.Text = "btn2";
        btn1.Hide();
        btn2.Hide();
        picB.Controls.Add(btn1);
        picB.Controls.Add(btn2);
        flp.Controls.Add(picB);
        picB.MouseEnter += picB_MouseEnter;
        picB.MouseLeave += picB_MouseLeave;
        btn1.MouseClick += btn1_MouseClick;
        btn2.MouseClick += btn2_MouseClick;
    }

    private void picB_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
        Button bt1 = (Button)pb.Controls[0];
        Button bt2 = (Button)pb.Controls[1];
        bt1.Show();
        bt2.Show();
    }

    private void picB_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
        Button bt1 = (Button)pb.Controls[0];
        Button bt2 = (Button)pb.Controls[1];
        bt1.Hide();
        bt2.Hide();
    }

    private void btn1_MouseClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button 1 pressed.");
    }

    private void btn2_MouseClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button 2 pressed.");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply test if the mouse is on/off **both** the `PictureBox` **and** your `Buttons`:

```
private void picB_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
    Button bt1 = (Button)pb.Controls[0];
    Button bt2 = (Button)pb.Controls[1];

    Point p = Control.MousePosition;
    if (bt1.ClientRectangle.Contains(bt1.PointToClient(p))  ||
        bt2.ClientRectangle.Contains(bt2.PointToClient(p))) return;

    bt1.Hide();
    bt2.Hide();
}
```

Comment: I have a problem with that pointer, i have 100 pictureBox in a flowLayoutPanel and when i clik on a button from those 100 pictureBox and move outside of that pictureBox, my scrollbar gets all the way up, how can i break that?

Comment: I think I have heard this before. You may want to  try to store the position `int location = this.flowLayoutPanel1.VerticalScroll.Value;` and restore it later.. Not sure just which event(s) should be used best, though..

Comment: I will try and let you know if i fixed it.

Comment: I've fixed it some other way, but thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

The `MouseLeave` event fires as soon as your mouse hovers over the button (the button will receive a `MouseEnter`. So they get hidden before you can click it.

I would not add those buttons to the picturebox but instead create a Panel that have both the PictureBox and the buttons.

```
var pnl = new Panel();
PictureBox picB = new PictureBox();
Button btn1 = new Button();
Button btn2 = new Button();
picB.Size = new Size(130, 70);
picB.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
btn1.Text = "btn1";
btn2.Text = "btn2";
btn1.Hide();
btn2.Hide();

pnl.Controls.Add(btn1);
pnl.Controls.Add(btn2);
pnl.Controls.Add(picB);

btn1.BringToFront();
btn2.BringToFront();

this.Controls.Add(pnl);

// picturebox and Panlel both handle MouseEnter
picB.MouseEnter += picAndpnl_MouseEnter;
pnl.MouseEnter += picAndpnl_MouseEnter;

pnl.MouseLeave += picB_MouseLeave;
btn1.MouseClick += btn1_MouseClick;
btn2.MouseClick += btn2_MouseClick;
```

And then in your events:

```
private void picAndpnl_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // check if this is the PictureBox or the Panel
    var ctl = (Control)sender;
    if (ctl is PictureBox)
    {
        ctl = ctl.Parent;
    }
    Button bt1 = (Button)ctl.Controls[0];
    Button bt2 = (Button)ctl.Controls[1];
    bt1.Show();
    bt2.Show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and for making me understand how this works.